# Add SSL sertificate in Laravel artisan serve Https

Tags: laravel, http, https, laravel-artisan, serve

I have project in laravel 5.7 version. I do authentication Facebook but i't work only https protocol. Please help. How i can add SSL to the local? I just can’t find any information on how to do this. I saw a couple of sources, but I did not understand anything.  I understand that this is not connected with Laravel. I described the situation as it is at the moment. Please tell me how to do this.

I watch this tutorial, but it's not work :( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH6evGKgy20

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the below article ?

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/198/enabling-ssl-https-protocol-with-xampp-in-a-local-php-project

You can setup SSL(https) with xampp in local.

Comment: I use wamp server.I’m going to my site like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/